# Can I edit coordinates within an edit session and reproject without reloading the data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, editing, xy

I have one lat/long to correct.  I edited within my table, saved edits, and now when I project using the Project tool the point stays on my map in the same position.  Do I need to reload my data from an edited Excel file or can I do it from within Arc?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS StackExchange. Please edit your question with the version of ArcMap you are using. Are you editing a table on ArcMap or a shapefile/featureclass/etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to make that change in Excel, you'll have to re-create the shapefile or feature class you're trying to edit and then project.

But - if you want to edit the X,Y of a point directly after you've created it from Excel, you can do this in an ArcGIS edit session using the [Edit Sketch Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_the_Edit_Sketch_Properties_window/01m80000001r000000/) dialogue:

[image]

Comment: @daveak Mapbaker basically already covered it, but to expand and explain xy (or lat long) coordinates in a table are essentially just attributes. Once a point geometry is created from those coordinates, they're not actually linked to the geometry anymore - that's stored in the `shape` field. So yes, you can edit the table in Arc, but you would still have to recreate the xy point layer for a change to take effect. Or, as this answer suggests, double-click the point in an edit session and change it on the Sketch Properties, which shows you the values in the `shape` field.

Comment: @daveak any luck on this?